# Ionic redirect to Homepage not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2

Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.navCtrl.push('home');
  }
}
```

First upon I removed many codes so login page is working properly. By using the same method I am redirecting the user to activation page that also working well but it not redirecting to homepage. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What error you are getting display here

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Component to which you are redirecting your page then you can do something like this to redirect or you can use any method if you want like after login button is hit choice is yours

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomeComponent } from 'your path to Home Component Page';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-login',
templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
NavParams) {
this.navCtrl.push(HomeComponent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to import your home path into login.ts and app.module.ts

```
import { home} from 'your path of home';
```